# Display a list of those who hav commented on a WordPress post, with links to their URL's.

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for a piece of PHP code or similar that would display a list of names/links of those who have commented on that WordPress post. This would sit at the bottom / top of a post.

The result might look something like: **Comments by:** [Name](http://example.com), [Name,](http://example.com) [Name](http://example.com).

I have looked at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments: So far, I've managed to get a list of all the names, however the list is repeated on all posts, even the ones that have no comments.

I'm a complete beginner at PHP, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

wordpress uses the  get_comment function to  store all comments on a page or post  you can do the  following.

```
      <?php 
               $args_comments = array(
                   'orderby' => 'comment_date','number' => 5,'status' => 
 'approve','post_id' => $postid,); 
               $recent_comments = get_comments( $args_comments );
               //var_dump($recent_comments);
               foreach ($recent_comments as $comment) {

                $id      = $comment->comment_ID;
                $author  = $comment->comment_author;
                $comment = $comment->comment_content;
                $date    = get_comment_date('l, F jS, Y', $id);
                $url     = get_comment_link($id); 
                $avater_url = get_avatar_url( $id );  
               $ava =  $avater_url;

                echo "<li><a href=". $url .">
                    <figure class='image is-48x48'> 
                       <img class='is-square' src=".$ava.">
                        </figure>
                     </a><a href=". $url ."><p>
                          ".$comment."
                        </p></a></li>";

            } ?>
```

This  is an example  on  how to loop  through the comments  if you place it at the bottom  of your template  it will get  all the comments of that page but you will have to  pass the post id  which you can get  by  placing this at the top of you page $postid = get_the_ID();

Comment: you can get the url  and the  comment author from the variable url and author above. thanks

Comment: Thanks, this does work, however gives me an Error 405 page when I go to post a new comment on a post.

Comment: Hi, with this code snippet, after clicking 'submit' to post a new comment, the wp-comments-post.php page will not load, and upon refreshing, the browser  returns this: "If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 405" I hope this helps.

Comment: I am posting the code in the index.php of my theme.

Comment: please var_dump $recent_comments and tell me what  you get, also  did  you g´create  a single.php or page.php ?

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm unsure how I would do that, I am a complete novice. The pages use a page.php format ,the posts use the index.php.